# LeetCode: Add Two Numbers (in Kotlin)

Tags: programming-challenge, kotlin

(...as I still learning Kotlin) I found [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/) "problem":

> You are given two linked lists representing two non-negative numbers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.
>
> **Input:** (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
>
> **Output:** 7 -> 0 -> 8

This is my solution so far:

```
fun add(a: IntArray, b: IntArray): Iterable<Int> {
  val result: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
  var remainder = 0
  for (i in 0..Math.max(a.size, b.size) - 1) {
    val sum = a.elementAtOrElse(i, { 0 }) + b.elementAtOrElse(i, { 0 }) + remainder
    remainder = if (sum >= 10) 1 else 0
    result.add(if (remainder >= 1) sum - 10 else sum)
  }
  if (remainder > 0) result.add(remainder)
  return result
}
```

...test cases:

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.Test

class AddTwoNumbersTest {
  @Test
  fun test_Add() {
    assertThat(add(intArrayOf(9, 6, 9, 5, 9), intArrayOf(1, 5, 1, 6, 1))).isEqualTo(listOf(0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1))
    assertThat(add(intArrayOf(4, 1, 8, 7, 2), intArrayOf(9, 4, 1, 0, 3))).isEqualTo(listOf(3, 6, 9, 7, 5))
    assertThat(add(intArrayOf(2, 2, 3, 3), intArrayOf(4, 5, 6, 7))).isEqualTo(listOf(6, 7, 9, 0, 1))
    assertThat(add(intArrayOf(4, 1, 0, 8), intArrayOf(2, 2, 7, 6))).isEqualTo(listOf(6, 3, 7, 4, 1))
    assertThat(add(intArrayOf(2, 7, 1, 0), intArrayOf(0, 0, 8, 1))).isEqualTo(listOf(2, 7, 9, 1))
    assertThat(add(intArrayOf(9, 9, 9), intArrayOf(9, 9, 9))).isEqualTo(listOf(8, 9, 9, 1))
    assertThat(add(intArrayOf(9, 3, 7), intArrayOf(8, 7, 8))).isEqualTo(listOf(7, 1, 6, 1))
    assertThat(add(intArrayOf(6, 6, 6), intArrayOf(7, 8, 9))).isEqualTo(listOf(3, 5, 6, 1))
    assertThat(add(intArrayOf(0, 0, 0), intArrayOf(0, 0, 0))).isEqualTo(listOf(0, 0, 0))
    assertThat(add(intArrayOf(2, 4, 3), intArrayOf(5, 6, 4))).isEqualTo(listOf(7, 0, 8))
    assertThat(add(intArrayOf(0, 1), intArrayOf(0, 1, 2))).isEqualTo(listOf(0, 2, 2))
    assertThat(add(intArrayOf(4, 6), intArrayOf(6, 4))).isEqualTo(listOf(0, 1, 1))
    assertThat(add(intArrayOf(1), intArrayOf(9, 9))).isEqualTo(listOf(0, 0, 1))
    assertThat(add(intArrayOf(), intArrayOf(0, 1))).isEqualTo(listOf(0, 1))
    assertThat(add(intArrayOf(), intArrayOf())).isEmpty()
  }
}
```

It works so far...so I'm wondering if you can improve this one, or have a better approach. Notice I use everything the language offer.

Comment: FYI: The "problem" calls for linked lists but you've used arrays. You might consider converting the Java code to Kotlin using IntelliJ IDEA or try.kotlinlang.org.

Comment: But leetcode has no support to judge your solution with Kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using `add` as a function name seems very ambiguous. The method name used in the Java `Solution` class from LeetCode seems more appropriate: `addTwoNumbers` (thereby specifying that the arguments, although not numbers themselves, represent numbers).
2. You can remove the explicit type specification for `var result` if you add explicit type arguments to `mutableListOf()`. I personally find this more readable and less verbose:

   ```
   var result = mutableListOf<Int>()
   ```
3. You can use `start until endExclusive` instead of `start..endInclusive - 1`:

   ```
   for (i in 0 until Math.max(a.size, b.size))
   ```
4. You can use the slightly shorter [`getOrElse`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-else.html) instead of [`elementAtOrElse`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/element-at-or-else.html). You can also move trailing lambda arguments out of parentheses:

   ```
   val sum = a.getOrElse(i) { 0 } + b.getOrElse(i) { 0 } + remainder
   ```
5. You can use an overloaded operator for adding elements to a mutable list:

   ```
   result += if (remainder >= 1) sum - 10 else sum
   ```
6. I wouldn't use `remainder >= 1` or `remainder > 0` because it makes it appear that `remainder` can be greater than `1` which is not true. I recommend using `remainder == 1`.

Altogether:

```
fun addTwoNumbers(a: IntArray, b: IntArray): Iterable<Int> {
    val result = mutableListOf<Int>()
    var remainder = 0
    for (i in 0 until Math.max(a.size, b.size)) {
        val sum = a.getOrElse(i) { 0 } + b.getOrElse(i) { 0 } + remainder
        remainder = if (sum >= 10) 1 else 0
        result += if (remainder == 1) sum - 10 else sum
    }
    if (remainder == 1) result.add(1)
    return result
}
```

However, the "problem" specified in LeetCode does not use arrays which are very different from linked lists. If you convert the Java code it provides you would get the following:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * class ListNode internal constructor(internal var `val`: Int) {
 *     internal var next: ListNode? = null
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    fun addTwoNumbers(l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode): ListNode {

    }
}
```

Solving such a problem should result in a *very* different solution than what you've arrived at.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware the solution would be completely different if I have to use their `ListNode` type; but I'm just "playing" with Kotlin right now, so I'm not pursuing the problem's solution as it's written, but something close that let me practice. BTW, your observations/recommendations are pretty cool...all of them!

Comment: Yeah, I would avoid using their `ListNode` too. :-) I'm glad I could help. An exercise in Kotlin that would be more similar and perhaps more entertaining would be to use `Sequence<Int>` instead of `IntArray`. `IntArray` allows random access to its elements and the size/length is known up front while `Sequence<Int>` does not and it would be inefficient to convert the `Sequence<Int>` to `IntArray`, `List<Int>`, etc.